# how to conditionally show a field on standard Edit page layout w/o recordtypes or profiles

Tags: page-layout

How to show any field in Edit Layouts (Not a VF) as per certain value of Field in salesforce.

I know If this will be VF we can use rendered but in Object layout how to hide/show any field as per certain value of Field meets

Answer (score 4):

I believe currently this is not possible in page layout.
Salesforce trying to possible this feature via lightning App builder.

Here is the Idea you can vote for this.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroxAAC

Answer from success community

> Salesforce doesnt support this. You can create field dependencies but
>   all fields always show up on the page at all times for users as long
>   as the field is included on the page layout and the field level
>   security gives them access to it.
>
> Promote this!!! -
>   http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brox

Source:- https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000go9uAAA

Comment: only 63000+ vote points; you think Benioff might take notice of this one :-)

Comment: @crop1645 Based on vote points, I think Yes. they will deliver this feature. what do you think?

Comment: I can only hope .... it would make point-and-click admin so much more powerful and aid tremendously in making layouts more compact for the 90% use cases where only a few fields are relevants and the waste-of-space fields are rarely populated